# material-ui-chip-input (ChipInput) Component always submit value

Tags: material-ui

I used 'ChipInput' component in create form and set default value to the component. After submit the form, not receive the value of 'ChipInput' component. Always receive empty value. I do not know where is the problem. Someone please help me. This is the code what I used.

```
<ChipInput
              value={['foo', 'bar']}
              name="test"
              source="test"
            />
```

Please someone tell me how to use 'ChipInput' inside form and post value to the API.

Answer (score 0):

set `defaultValue` instead of `value`

```
<ChipInput
    defaultValue={['foo', 'bar']}
    name="test"
    source="test"
/>
```